# Android-Cannot pass a String to a method in another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have two activities, MainActivity and NearbyPlacesActivity.
I am trying to pass a string from NearbyPlacesActivity to the method show() in MainActivity. However, I end up with an error saying:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Here's NearbyPlacesActivity:

```
private void showNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlaceList)
{
    ArrayList<String> list_names = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < nearbyPlaceList.size(); i++)
    {

        HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = nearbyPlaceList.get(i);
        String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
        list_names.add(placeName);
    }

    String alist = list_names.toString();
    String blist = alist.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");

    MainActivity main=new MainActivity();
    main.show(blist);

}
```

and here's the show method in MainActivity:

```
public void show(String blist){
    random_text.setText(blist);
}
```

I could setText from within MainActivity just fine, but can't seem to pass any variables from NearbyPlacesActivity. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You cannot create objects of activities like `MainActivity main=new MainActivity();` You need to pass values using `Intent`.

Comment: You cannot pass directly data using new Activity()  you need to pass data using intent or via implementing listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do that to open an activity in android.
Android works with intents so if you want to open main activity and pass data to it. Just use the following

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NearbyPlacesActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("string_key","string_value");
startActivity(intent);
```

If you want only to pass data to a method inside another activity. You should hold a reference to that activity so that you can use its underlying methods.
The refrence is set on onResume and unset on onDispose

Answer (score 0):

Pass data using intent. Do not instantiate the activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("YOUR_KEY", list);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use Intent:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(NearbyPlacesActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("myblist", blist);
    startActivity(i);
```

And in MainActivity.java:

```
    if(getIntent().getExtras() != null)
    {
        String blist = getIntent().getExtras().getString("myblist");
        show(blist);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers given are here aren't wrong but they are incomplete in my opinion. The best way to do this with validations is to make sure that the extra is taken from the previous Activity as well as the savedInstanceState which is the Bundle data received while starting the Activity and can be passed back to onCreate if the activity needs to be recreated (e.g., orientation change) so that you don't lose this prior information. If no data was supplied, savedInstanceState is null.

> Sending data -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("name", "Jon Snow");
intent.putExtra("number", "7");
startActivity(intent);
```

> Receiving data -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);

    int no;
    String na;

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(extras != null){
            no = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("number"));
            na = extras.getString("name");
        }

    }else{
        no = (int) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("number");
        na = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("name");
    }

    // Other code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to start your NearbyPlacesActivity as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NearbyPlacesActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);
```

and then in your MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1234) {
        if (data.hasExtra("list"){
            String list = data.getStringExtra("list");
            show(list);
        }
    }
}
```

and in your NearByPlacesActivity.class

```
private void showNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlaceList)
{
    ArrayList<String> list_names = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < nearbyPlaceList.size(); i++)
    {

        HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = nearbyPlaceList.get(i);
        String placeName = googlePlace.get("place_name");
        list_names.add(placeName);
    }

    String alist = list_names.toString();
    String blist = alist.replace("[", "").replace("]", "");

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("list", blist);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    this.finish();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### On First Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NearbyPlacesActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("string_key","string_value");
startActivity(intent);
```

### On Second Activity:

```
 Intent intent=getIntent();
 String strValue=intent.getStringExtra("string_key");
```